# KSQL - Need to fetch data programmatically

Tags: ksqldb, confluent-platform

I want to fetch data from a KSQL query result from a java service. Can you please suggest the way? Is it to be done via KSQL REST API?

Comment: If one of the answers below addressed your question, please mark it as Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your wording is a bit ambiguous, so I give you two answers:

1. **You want to query KSQL (has the information) from an external service (needs the information).** Here, you'd use the KSQL REST API as you suggested.
2. **You want to query an external service (has the information) from KSQL (needs the information).** Here, you could write a KSQL User Defined Function (UDF), which are implemented in Java, and call your external Java service through it: https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/udf.html.

Comment: It seems the we can call the UDF from a KSQL. But how to call the result of a streaming query from a java service deployed out side ( may be as AWS Lambda )

Comment: For the opposite direction, i.e., you want to query KSQL from an external service, you'd use the KSQL REST API (as you suggested). I updated the answer.

Comment: Hi Michael, another issue. The REST call is not sending a valid JSON. Is there any library to get a proper JSON ?     | jq '.' is not working from a command line for me and can not be used inside a java program I believe. Can you please suggest ?                                                         
 Eg . curl -X "POST" "http://localhost:8088/ksql" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.ksql.v1+json; charset=utf-8" \
     -d $'{
  "ksql": "LIST STREAMS;",
  "streamsProperties": {}
}'

Comment: First, please mark this answer as accepted if it does answer your original question above.  Second, please create a new SO question for your follow-up question.